# fancyhdr.sty not found

Tags: fancyhdr

I have been trying to add `fancyhdr.sty` to my LaTex using `\usepackage`, but it will not work. The installation appears to be successful, but the second I try to run the package, I get a message saying

> fancyhdr.sty not found.

I also tried to manually install the file in `/tex/latex` folder, but that didn't work either. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to get the file to successfully install?

Comment: Which TeX system are you using? Did you use its package manager to install the package?

Comment: MikTeX 2.9 is my system for running LaTeX through TeXStudio. I don't know how to use the package manager for it